# Presenting MYSQL nested JSON object with php

Tags: php, json, http, mysqli

I have a MYSQL Table stored using 000webhostapp cpanel, here is what it look like.

```
id | name  |             J_Object
--------------------------------------------------------- 
1  | deckA | {"type":"A", "ports": {"hdmi": 1, "usb":2}}
2  | deckB | {"type":"B", "ports": {"hdmi": 3, "usb":2}}
3  | deckC | {"type":"A", "ports": {"hdmi": 1, "usb":2}}
4  | deckD | {"type":"B", "ports": {"hdmi": 3, "usb":2}}
```

Using PHP, I would like to present it like the below to act as a HTTP to pass the data to other platforms.

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "deckA",
        "J_Object": [{"type":"A", "ports": {"hdmi": 1, "usb":2}}]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "deckB",
        "J_Object": [{"type":"B", "ports": {"hdmi": 3, "usb":2}}]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "deckC",
        "J_Object": [{"type":"A", "ports": {"hdmi": 1, "usb":2}}]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "deckD",
        "J_Object": [{"type":"B", "ports": {"hdmi": 3, "usb":2}}]
    }
]
```

However, with my PHP I written below, what follows after is what I got. And it is definitely not what I wanted.

The PHP code:

```
$search = "SELECT * FROM `database`.`products` 
            WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`J_Object` , '$.ports.usb') > 2 
            AND JSON_EXTRACT(`J_Object` , '$.ports.hdmi') > 1;";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $search);

if ($result) {
    //Printing out the details of the rows

    while($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $jsonData[]=$array;
    }

    $nonArr = json_encode($jsonData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $stringArr = (string)$nonArr;
    $nonSlash = str_replace("\\","", $stringArr);
    echo $nonSlash;
}  

mysqli_close($link)
```

And the below is the unwanted results:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "deckA",
        "J_Object": "{"type":"A", "ports": {"hdmi": 1, "usb":2}}"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "deckB",
        "J_Object": "{"type":"B", "ports": {"hdmi": 3, "usb":2}}'
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "deckC",
        "J_Object": "{"type":"A", "ports": {"hdmi": 1, "usb":2}}"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "deckD",
        "J_Object": "{"type":"B", "ports": {"hdmi": 3, "usb":2}}"
    }
]
```

It looks like its the same but if you notice the [ ] is changed with " " which also means that the nested object is not quite right.
Can any pro out there show me how do I get the correct output?

Comment: I dont get why you are storing the json when you could either have other columns (type, port_hdmi and port_usb) or another table to store those data. Also i dont understand why you want the result as an array although it is not store like this

Comment: Hi @Zyigh I store as a json so that I can have scalability and they save up some space. Also I have edited a little as they are stored as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a much simpler way.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $search);

if ($result) {
    //Printing out the details of the rows

    while($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $array['J_Object'] = [json_decode($array['J_Object'], true)];
        $jsonData[]=$array;
    }

    echo json_encode($jsonData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you. It's just a quick fix with preg_replace.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $search);

if ($result) {
    //Printing out the details of the rows

    while($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $jsonData[]=$array;
    }

    $nonArr = json_encode($jsonData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $stringArr = (string)$nonArr;
    $nonSlash = str_replace("\\","", $stringArr);

    // quick fix
    $nonSlash = preg_replace("/[\"]{1}[{]{1}/", '[{', $nonSlash);
    $nonSlash = preg_replace("/[}]{1}[\"]{1}/", '}]', $nonSlash);
    echo $nonSlash;
}
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "deckA",
        "J_Object": [{"type":"A", "ports": {"hdmi": 1, "usb":2}}]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "deckB",
        "J_Object": [{"type":"B", "ports": {"hdmi": 3, "usb":2}}]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "deckC",
        "J_Object": [{"type":"A", "ports": {"hdmi": 1, "usb":2}}]
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "deckD",
        "J_Object": [{"type":"B", "ports": {"hdmi": 3, "usb":2}}]
    }
]
```

Hope you find this helpful. Happy coding..